# Haskell: I seem to not be able to link anything to my accumulator in following recursive function - can anyone explain where I am wrong here?

Tags: list, function, haskell, recursion, linked-list

Task:
"Define a function 'start' that returns all the elements of a given list but the last one"

My solution:

```
start list = start' list []
    where
        start' (x:[]) acc = acc
        start' (x:xs) acc = start' xs (acc:x)
```

When trying to compile, ghc seems to throw an error because of the very last expression in line 4 at '(acc:x)'.
Can somebody explain, why that is?
I don't really care if this is the most efficient way of solving this problem - I just want to get where I am wrong.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: hint: which of `x` and `acc` is a list, and which is an individual element?

Comment: x would be the head of the list, which is recursively added to acc to form a new list without the last element of the original list

Answer (score 3):

`(acc:x)` makes not much sense: `acc` is a list, `x` is an element. `(:) :: a -> [a] -> [a]` takes an item and a list, and construct a list where the item is the first item and the given list is the list of remaining items in the result.

You can append at the right end with:

```
start list = start' list []
  where
    start' (x : []) acc = acc
    start' (x : xs) acc = start' xs (acc ++ [x])
```

Your `start` here basically does what [**`init :: [a] -> [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.18.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:init) does, except that your `start` version also works for empty lists.

Using an accumulator however is not necessary and will only increase the computational effort and memory usage. You can work with:

```
start :: [a] -> [a]
start [] = []
start (x : xs) = go xs x
  where
    go [] _ = []
    go (x : xs) y = y : go xs x
```

or shorter:

```
start :: [a] -> [a]
start [] = []
start (x : xs) = go xs x
  where
    go [] = const []
    go (x : xs) = (: go xs x)
```

This allows to work with infinite lists as well, where the `start` will never stop, but only needs a limited amount of memory.